# How to loop with two lists in R

Tags: r, list, loops, nested

I have a dataset with demographic information and with questions.

```
DF<-(Participant = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
Male = c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0)
Female = c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1)
Q1 = c(9,6,5,4,5,1,3,5,5,2)
Q2 = c(2,4,5,4,2,1,3,5,4,2)
Q3 = c(6,8,2,7,5,2,1,1,6,3))
```

I have two lists (made from column titles), one of demographic information (Males, Females, age group etc) and one of questions with their associated response.

```
Demographic <- c(“Male”, “Female”, “Age_group_1”, “Age_group_2”…)
Questions<- c(“Q1”, “Q2”, Q3”, “Q4”…)
```

I need something along the lines of- if value in demographic column is equal to 1 then sum scores in all separate question columns. But I want to do this is a loop so I have the separate question scores (~300) for all columns in the demographic list (~80). Plus I want to save the output. I have no idea how to do this and I’m getting into a loop of bad programming myself!

The end result should resemble this:

```
   M  F
Q1 20 21
Q2 16 16
Q3 23 18
```

I would be grateful for any help!

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

With help from a friend, I have found a work around my problem. How do you make this more efficient though?

```
df.list <- list()
for(question in questions){
  question.df <- (DF[, lapply(.SD,sum, na.rm=T), by=question, 
.SDcols=c(demographic)])
  df.list <- append(df.list, question.df)}

list_new <- bind_cols(df.list, .id = "column_label")
```

Comment: The first block of code does not run properly.
Perhaps you meant :

`
DF <- data.frame(
  Participant = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  Male = c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0),
  Female = c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1),
  Q1 = c(9,6,5,4,5,1,3,5,5,2),
  Q2 = c(2,4,5,4,2,1,3,5,4,2),
  Q3 = c(6,8,2,7,5,2,1,1,6,3)
)
`

If so, please update your first message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do with the output, another approach is to use `tables::tabular()`, which can be used to generate additional statistics (e.g. percentages), as well as customizing row and column headings.

We'll generate a simple table using the data provided in the question.

```
df <- data.frame(Participant = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
     Male = c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0),
     Female = c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1),
     Q1 = c(9,6,5,4,5,1,3,5,5,2),
     Q2 = c(2,4,5,4,2,1,3,5,4,2),
     Q3 = c(6,8,2,7,5,2,1,1,6,3))
df$sex <- ifelse(df$Male == 1,"M","F")
library(tables)
tabular((Q1 + Q2 + Q3)~Factor(sex)*(sum),data=df)
```

...and the output:

```
> tabular((Q1 + Q2 + Q3)~Factor(sex)*(sum),data=df)
           
    sex    
    F   M  
    sum sum
 Q1 21  24 
 Q2 16  16 
 Q3 18  23
```

### Processing multiple demographic variables

In the comments to my answer a question was asked about how to use `tabular()` with more than one demographic variable.

We can use a combination of `lapply()`, `paste()`, and `substitute()` to build the correct formula expressions for `tabular().

To illustrate the process we will add a second demographic variable, `Income` to the data frame listed above. Then we create a vector to represent the list of demographic variables for which we will generate tables. Finally, we use the vector with `lapply()` to produce the tables.

```
df <- data.frame(Participant = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
     Male = c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0),
     Female = c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1),
     Income = c(rep("low",5),rep("high",5)),
     Q1 = c(9,6,5,4,5,1,3,5,5,2),
     Q2 = c(2,4,5,4,2,1,3,5,4,2),
     Q3 = c(6,8,2,7,5,2,1,1,6,3))
df$Sex <- ifelse(df$Male == 1,"M","F")
library(tables)
tabular((Q1 + Q2 + Q3)~Factor(Sex)*(sum),data=df)

demoVars <- c("Sex","Income")

lapply(demoVars,function(x){
        # generate a formula expression including the column variable
        # and use substitute() to render it correctly within tabular() 
        theExpr <- paste0("(Q1 + Q2 + Q3) ~ Factor(",x,")*(sum)")
        tabular(substitute(theExpr),data=df)
})
```

...and the output:

```
> lapply(demoVars,function(x){
+         # generate a formula expression including the column variable
+         # and use substitute() to render it correctly within tabular() 
+         theExpr <- paste0("(Q1 + Q2 + Q3) ~ Factor(",x,")*(sum)")
+         tabular(substitute(theExpr),data=df)
+ })
[[1]]
           
    Sex    
    F   M  
    sum sum
 Q1 21  24 
 Q2 16  16 
 Q3 18  23 

[[2]]
              
    Income    
    high   low
    sum    sum
 Q1 16     29 
 Q2 15     17 
 Q3 13     28
```

Note that we can enhance the solution further by saving the tables to an output object and rendering them in a printer friendly format as needed.

Comment: That's really useful, but how do I iterate through a list of 80 demographic variables?

Comment: @lightsout -  We can use `lapply()` to generate a set of tables, one for each demographic variable. I'll post an update illustrating how to do that within the next 24 hours or so.

Comment: Thank you Len! That would be so useful you can't believe.

Comment: @lightsout - as promised, I added code to illustrate how to use `tabular()` to generate multiple tables with various demographic variables.

Comment: You Le(n)gend! Thank you.

Comment: @lightsout - you're welcome. If you found my answer to be helpful, please upvote and accept it.

Comment: Hi Len, is there a way to create a list outside of the function of question names like you have done for the "demoVars" variables?

Comment: @lightsout -  Yes, this can be done with regular expressions along with the `rownames()` function. `dplyr` also has functions for selecting columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
    Participant = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
     Male = c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0),
     Female = c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1),
     Q1 = c(9,6,5,4,5,1,3,5,5,2),
     Q2 = c(2,4,5,4,2,1,3,5,4,2),
     Q3 = c(6,8,2,7,5,2,1,1,6,3)
)

df %>% 
  mutate(sex = ifelse(Male == 1, "M", "F")) %>%
  select(-Male, -Female) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Q"), names_to = "Q") %>%
  group_by(sex, Q) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = sex)
```

gives:

```
  Q         F     M
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Q1       21    24
2 Q2       16    16
3 Q3       18    23
```